# I'm getting custom asana headers with a task query

Tags: asana

I am making a task query to asana. I have a custom header that I made called holding pattern. It is not a task it is a custom header. In the task query the custom header is pretending to be a task and coming in with the task call. Why is this and how would I exclude it?

Comment: Can you share the actual HTTP request and response? Would make it easier to figure out what's going on.

Comment: For example using `curl -v`, that includes all the headers both ways as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Here is what I found. Custom headers in asana are tasks that have a colon at the end. Asana then knows to treat them like labels, but it still comes in as a task in the query call. I had to write,

```
var lastChar = task.substr(task.length -1);
if (lastChar != ":"){
    //basically don't include it as a task.
}
```

I was already manually pushing each task to my own array one by one so I could attach it to it's project, so I just made it to where it doesn't push the tasks with colons on the end. I did not understand when I posted question what made it a custom header.
edit from first post:
I have a custom header which **Someone else** created. It just seemed easier to say I made it.
    When I talked to the guy who made it he told me what it was he did, and then I was able to figure out what made it different than a task and exclude it.